# Data Cleanup with Regex

Tags: python, regex, awk, sed, data-cleaning

I have a very large number of very large files.

Each file contains lines Like this:

```
uuid1 (tab) data1 (vtab) data2 ...  dataN
uuid2 (tab) data1' (vtab) data2' (vtab) data3' (vtab) ...  dataN'
....
```

where N will be different for every line. The result needs to look like:

```
uuid1 (tab) data1
uuid1 (tab) data2
....
uuid1 (tab) dataN
uuid2 (tab) data1'
uuid2 (tab) data2'
uuid2 (tab) data3'
...  
uuid2 (tab) dataN'
....
```

I have a regex that does the job, replacing:

```
^([abcdef0123456789]{8}-[abcdef0123456789]{4}-[abcdef0123456789]{4}-[abcdef0123456789]{4}-[abcdef0123456789]{12})\t(.+?)\x0B
```

with:

```
\1\t\2\n\1\t
```

but it's slow, and needs repeated applications, obviously.

Is there a quicker programmatic way to perform this across all the files?

Tools available in the toolbox: unix tools (sed, awk etc), python, possibly perl.

Not looking for a religious war, just a pragmatic approach.

**Additional Info**

Here's the complete script I used, based on Kristof's script, for handling the outer loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import uuid

def processFile( in_filename ):

  out_filename = os.path.splitext(in_filename)[0] + '.result.txt'

  with open(in_filename) as f_in:
    with open(out_filename, 'w') as f_out:
      for line in f_in:
        try:
          # Retrieve the line and split into UUID and data
          line_uuid, data = line.split('\t')
          # Validate UUID
          uuid.UUID(line_uuid)
        except ValueError:
          # Ignore this line
          continue
        # Write each individual piece of data to a separate line
        for data_part in data.rstrip().split('\x0b'):
          f_out.write(line_uuid + '\t' + data_part  + '\n')

for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
  if i.endswith(".txt"): 
    print i
    processFile( i )
    continue
  else:
    continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation in Python (tested in 3.5). I haven't tried this on a large data set, I'll leave that for you to try out.

```
import uuid

in_filename = 'test.txt'
out_filename = 'parsed.txt'

with open(in_filename) as f_in:
    with open(out_filename, 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            try:
                # Retrieve the line and split into UUID and data
                line_uuid, data = line.split('\t', maxsplit=1)
                # Validate UUID
                uuid.UUID(line_uuid)
            except ValueError:
                # Ignore this line
                continue
            # Write each individual piece of data to a separate line
            for data_part in data.rstrip().split('\x0b'):
                f_out.write(line_uuid + '\t' + data_part  + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an awk script:

**script.awk:**

```
BEGIN { FS="[\t\v]" }
      { for(i=2 ; i <= NF; i++ ) printf("%s\t%s\n",$1,$i) }
```

like this: `awk -f script.awk yourfile`

(I have not tried this with a large dataset and I am really interested how it performs compared to other solutions.)

Comment: It could be an advantage to have sed replace the `\v` with `\t` before: `sed 's/\v/\t/g' yourfile > test.csv` and comment out the first line in `script.awk` so that the splitting is done with a fixed string (tab) instead of the regular expression.

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk. Field splitting is always done with a regexp, never a string - any specified string is converted to a regexp before the field splitting occurs. Tweak: `OFS="\t" ... print $1, $i`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an awk script that will also check the uuid.

It ignores lines without a valid uuid.

```
BEGIN { FS="\v"; OFS="\t" }
{
  split($1,a,/\s+/);
  if (match(a[1], /^[a-f0-9]{8}(-[a-f0-9]{4}){3}-[a-f0-9]{12}$/, m))
  {
    print a[1],a[2];
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print a[1],$i;
  }
}
```

Testing it on a small file in the format:
uuid (normal tab) data1 (vertical tab) data2 ... (vertical tab) dataN

If you're certain that the uuid's are already valid, then removing the `if` will naturally speed it up since the regex match takes a bit of time. But probably the speed of your filesystem might prove to be a bigger bottleneck.

```
$ awk -f unpivot_data.awk input.txt > result.txt

$ cat result.txt
abcd1234-ab12-ab12-ab12-abcdef123456    data1
abcd1234-ab12-ab12-ab12-abcdef123456    data2
```

And to be honest, I hope that once you've tested the different solutions, that you could share with us how much faster/slower the processing of such a huge file has become.